# Why my C program can't read data from file using "<" character

Tags: c, scanf, batch-processing

I am writing a demo C application in batch mode, which will try to read from a file as input.
The command is : `metric <mydata`

The C source file is:

```
/* Converts distances from miles to kilometers.  */

#include <stdio.h>  /* printf, scanf definitions */
#define KMS_PER_MILE 1.609 /* conversion constants */

int main(void)
{
    double miles, /* distance in miles    */
           kms;  /* equivalent distance in kilometers */

    /* Get and echo the distance in miles. */
    scanf("1f", &miles);
    printf("The distance in miles is %.2f.\n", miles);

    /* Convert the distance to kilometers. */
    kms = KMS_PER_MILE * miles;

    /* Display the distance in kilometers. */
    printf("That equals %.2f kilometers.\n", kms);

    return (0);
}
```

The file "mydata" contains simply an integer 100

When I run the command `metric <mydata`. The output is:

```
The distance in miles is 0.00.
That equals 0.00 kilometers.
```

Is there any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, but you should check the `scanf` return value to find out whether the value was successfully read. (The actual problem is invalid format string, i.e., missing `%`.)

Comment: @Arkku: I wouldn't call it unrelated to the actual question. If OP had checked the return value of `scanf`, then it would have been immediately apparent that `scanf` was not matching any arguments.

Comment: you need to test the return value of your scanf: `if (<yourscanf> != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "Got unexpected value from scanf!\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misread the doc: instead of `scanf("1f", &miles);` you should write:

```
scanf("%lf", &miles);
```

Testing the return value of `scanf()` avoids undefined behavior when the conversion fails and would have helped detect this error.  Enabling all warnings in your compiler (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`) is also recommended to avoid silly mistakes.

Here is a modified version:

```
/* Converts distances from miles to kilometers.  */

#include <stdio.h>  /* printf, scanf definitions */

#define KMS_PER_MILE 1.609 /* conversion constants */

int main(void) {
    double miles; /* distance in miles    */
    double kms;  /* equivalent distance in kilometers */

    /* Get and echo the distance in miles. */
    if (scanf("%lf", &miles) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("The distance in miles is %.2f.\n", miles);

    /* Convert the distance to kilometers. */
    kms = KMS_PER_MILE * miles;

    /* Display the distance in kilometers. */
    printf("That equals %.2f kilometers.\n", kms);

    return 0;
}
```